# ¿Cómo evitar separación de palabra y otros caracteres?

Tags: php

Son casos especiales, a lo mejor no sucederá nunca, pero es mejor tener una función que funcione en todos los casos especiales.

Tengo dos campos uno que es el titulo, y el `textarea` donde escribo el articulo.

Si en el formulario, se escribe un carácter especial al último o otros caracteres en los títulos por ejemplo:

**1. Titulo: Escribo / algo /**

- Resultado URL: `escribo-algo-`
- Lo ideal: `escribo-algo`

**2. Titulo: ¿Cómo escribir algo?**

- Resultado URL: `-iquest-como-escribir-algo-e-`
- Lo ideal: `como-escribir-algo`

**3. Titulo: Añadidura Ñaque ñoño**

- Resultado URL: `a-ntilde-adidura-ntilde-aque-ntilde-o-ntilde-o`
- Lo ideal: `anadidura-naque-nono`

**4. Titulo: categoría comunicación producción**

- Resultado URL: `categor-iacute-a-comunicaci-oacute-n-producci-oacute-n-`

  > Nota: Al final se agrego esto `-` porque deje un espacio al final del titulo
- Lo ideal: `categoria-comunicacion-produccion`

Si se deja un espacio al final del texto `algo con espacio` igual `algo-con-`
Lo mismo funciona si se agrega al final del texto caracteres `?!.`otros el resultado es que agregara al final esto `url-`

Tengo la siguiente función, como puedo corregir los errores y permitir una cantidad de palabras es decir permitir crear la URL con 20 caracteres y así el usuario crea una titulo extenso no creara una URL extensa.

```
function php_slug($string){
    $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', strtolower($string));
    return $slug;
}
```

Comment: Si no es a modo de ejercicio para aprender o conocer mejor como crear los _slug_ y estas buscando una solución, puede que te interese esto: [cocur/slugify](https://github.com/cocur/slugify)

Comment: @OscarR Gracias por el enlace, pero no me gusta usar librerías de terceros, cuando se puede aprender hacer algo nativa-mente :) las librerías quedan para proyectos grandes ya realizados como sistemas u otros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal mira tu función SLUG aún falta completar para que puedas realizar slug tal cual deseas y hay un detalle que no incluiste y es ¿Qué sucede en caso de los acentos?.

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8"); 
function slugword($text){
    // replace non letter or digits by -

    $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

    // transliterate
    $text = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');

    // remove duplicated - symbols
    $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);

    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);

    if (empty($text)) {
      return 'n-a';
    }

    return $text;
}



$url = slugword('¿Cómo preguntar algó?');

echo $url;
```

Resultado :
anadidura-naque-nono

Con respecto a los caracteres, eso tu lo puedes limitar con la siguiente
función nativa de php condicionando el valor retornado por la función

[int strlen ( string $string )](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php)

Saludos.

Comment: Si lo agregue amigo también los acentos, aunque no especifique, pero si en los ejemplos: **categoría comunicación producción** lo ideal: `categoria-comunicacion-produccion`

Comment: De cualquier manera la función ya lo realiza, te invito a que compruebes si la respuesta te ayudo en caso de que si marcar con palomita verde :D

Comment: Lo estoy probando amigo ya te comento :)

Comment: Sigue generando URL mal, pongo esto en el **titulo** `¿Cómo preguntar algó?` y el resultado de la **URL** es `iquest-c-oacute-mo-preguntar-alg-oacute` lo ideal es: `como-preguntar-algo`

Comment: Los acentos o tildes generan URL no deseada: **Titulo:**  `títulos con acentos á á otros caracteres +` **resultado URL:** `t-iacute-tulos-con-acentos-aacute-aacute-otros-caracteres` **Lo ideal:** `titulos-con-acentos-a-a-otros-caracteres`

Comment: Lo mismo sucede con este **Titulo:** `ñaño ñaño` **resultado URL** `ntilde-a-ntilde-o-ntilde-a-ntilde-o` **Lo ideal:** `nano-nano`

Comment: Revísalo de nuevo , por que solo era hacer un ajuste de ascii

Comment: Sigue mostrando los mismos errores que le comente a **Rene Limon**

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec265d3714714b475bdd7377504d1f836d23b23a

Comment: si ya funciona, el historial estaba ejecutando estos malos caracteres ambas respuestas funciona bien :)

Answer (score 2):

Yo utilizo esta función:

```
function limpiartitulo($string){
    $string = trim( strtolower($string) );
    $string = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replace spaces to hyphens.
    $string = preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"),$string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
    if (substr($string, -1) === '-' )
        $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
    $string = preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", $string);
    return strtolower($string);
}

$cadena="Escribo / algo /";
echo limpiartitulo($cadena)."<br>";
// "escribo-algo"

$cadena="¿Cómo escribir algo?";
echo limpiartitulo($cadena)."<br>";
// "como-escribir-algo"

$cadena="Añadidura Ñaque ñoño";
echo limpiartitulo($cadena)."<br>";
// "anadidura-naque-nono"

$cadena="categoría comunicación producción ";
echo limpiartitulo($cadena)."<br>";
// "categoria-comunicacion-produccion"
```

Y cada salida mantiene la integridad de la frase.

Nota:
En los caso en donde obtienes resultados como:

> ¿Cómo aprender ingles? -> iquestcoacutemo-aprender-ingles

es porque estás obteniendo el texto como sus entidades html y lo que te devuelve es el código de la entidad ([Ver tabla de códigos de entidades](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_i.asp)).

Probablemente estés utilizando la funcion htmlspecialchars() o alguna smilar que esta conviertiendo los caracteres a sus entidades html. Revisa esta [respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31487473/4987172).

Comment: Hola, voy a chequearlo ahorita ya te comento, gracias por responder :)

Comment: Me genera mal las URL :( Ejemplos probados: **Titulo:** ¿Cómo aprender ingles? **Resultado Url**: `iquestcoacutemo-aprender-ingles` Lo ideal: `como-aprender-ingles` Otro **Titulo:** Títulos con caracteres + ! ? . especiales y letras ñ y espacios **Resultado URL:** `tiacutetulos-con-caracteres-----especiales-y-letras-ntilde-y-espacios` Lo ideal `titulos-con-caracteres-especiales-y-letras-n-y-espacios`

Comment: El de **¿Cómo aprender ingles?** lo probé y a mi si me lo muestra correctamente. Corregí la función cuando repite los guiones.

Comment: Qué versión de PHP utilizas ? Por que el código funciona correctamente y trata de evitar escribir "resultado" e "ideal" por que en la pregunta ya lo formulas y quienes escriben la respuesta es por que lograron obtener lo "ideal" revisa este link http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec265d3714714b475bdd7377504d1f836d23b23a

Comment: el de @ReneLimon tambien funciona correctamente como el que te escribi http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e182a759b213bf2bc17259f99204dd0c22c705d1

Comment: @frank_ivan Voy a borrar el historial, porque a mi sigue saliendo los errores :( ya les comento

Comment: @ReneLimon Ambas respuestas funciona correctamente :) + 1 gracias

Comment: ok, edite la respuesta para aclarar el problema que tienas con los signos de interrogación